# Wordpress Custom Post Loop - How to not print information from an Array that I don't need?

Tags: php, wordpress

Been using the plugin Custom Content Type Manager to create a custom post that displays location information. 
We hold weekly games for each location - So what I'm trying to accomplish is in my custom post I have a set of checkboxes so you check if the venue is played on Monday, Tuesday or Wed...etc Then in my theme I'm going to have a 7 day calendar. And if a location is checked for that day then I want the title/links to the location printed there.

I'm giving you that background because I really dont think I'm going about this the correct way. Essentially I'm doing it in a loop, and I'm pulling all the checkbox options in an Array, and if the option is equal to Monday to that specific day, then it prints the locations title name etc. 
I want this setup so a non-technical person (kinda like me lol) can just add a new location and pick "friday" for example and the code does the rest. 
Essentially I got it working. 2 problems though

1. I'm running 7 loops to accomplish this - one for each day. I know this is stupid and there is probably a better solution.
2. It's printing the correct information - however its also reading/printing each of the other locations except its not putting up the info for them - I know this cause its creating empty DIVs for them.

**NOTE: I'm having issues posting the whole code...?? I deleted all the php tags to present this**

```
$weekly = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'locations', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
while ( $weekly->have_posts() ) : $weekly->the_post();
<div class="weekly-venue-spacer"> 
$day_array = get_custom_field('weekly_day:to_array'); 
if (in_array('3', $day_array)) {
print_custom_field('venue_display_name');
echo "<br />";
print_custom_field('city_crossroads');  
}
</div>
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

the '3' in the in_array statement just means "Wednesday".

Here look at this image:
http://i40.tinypic.com/svnee0.jpg
an example of the empty DIVs being created - easily seen with padding applied to the div

Thanks for reading. Any solution to approach this differently would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understood correctly what you want , but assuming I did - I think your whole approach is a bit wrong/complicated .

First of all, you do not need 7 loops .

I have noticed have a custom field - so in that custom field , instead of an array, just store the ONE day that you need , and then simply GET by checking the custom_field value ..

Second - why do you use checkbook and not a list ? is there an eventual event that can be in several different days ? because if every event is exclusive for one day - than it would be more easy to use a drop list or even radio buttons.

and for your direct question - I do not know how the value of the custom field is structured - but you are printing ALL of it ..

**EDIT I :** After reading comment and understanding better the problem -

While still thinking that the approach is a bit wrong , but not knowing exactly how you construct the data - I will address the IMMEDIATE problem :

The code creates empty DIVS simply because you tell it to .
you are using a `WHILE` condition in the code BEFORE outputting a div.
Since your query gets 5 posts - it will create 5 divs (some of which that do not meet the NEXT condition , will be of course empty).

your function now , put in human-words is working like this :

```
 1. Get 5 post. 
 2. As long as I have posts (for each post), Open a div. 
 3. If you have Tuesday in array - print something
 4. close div
 5. if not finished all posts (in our case, 5) - go back to step 2.
```

It is obvious that the code will print empty div also for empty events..

So to get it right you simply move the opening div tag to BEFORE the `WHILE` condition .

that is if you do not need to check for existence of events in the query ..

The right way would be to use also the `IF` statement, just like the regular wordpress loop.

The general mechanism is this :

```
   <?php if ($weekly->have_posts()) : ?>
//now we open a div
               <?php while ( $weekly->have_posts() ) : $weekly->the_post();?> 
     // now we check for other conditions and print them if available.
               <?php endwhile; ?>
// now we close the DIV
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for answering. Yeah I know I'm approaching it in a complicated unnecessary way, but I'm learning. haha

Yes the problem is for my custom "location" posts is that alot of the locations play on multiple days. So one location will hold an event on a Monday and also a Saturday for example. So I need to be able to choose multiple days and the code will place them correctly... I will try messing around with a GET approach. Thanks. Any quick general example of how I would GET the posts bases on the value?